# Capture result of bash anonymous FIFO

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm working on a script that uses an anonymous FIFO to take the output of a command which expects an output file as a parameter and feed it into a command that accepts input from stdin. The setup looks like this:

```
OUTPUT=$( cmd1 args >( cmd2 args - ) 2>&1 )

echo $? # echoes 0
```

What I want to do is optionally echo the `OUTPUT` if the result of `cmd2` was not zero. The `$?` appears to reflect either the assignment of `OUTPUT` or the result of `cmd1`, because if I run the following `1` is echoed but `$?` is `0`.

```
OUTPUT=$( cmd1 args >( cmd2 args - ; echo $?) 2>&1 )    # echoes 1

echo $? # echoes 0
```

The `$PIPESTATUS` special variable also matches the output of `$?`.

```
OUTPUT=$( cmd1 args >( cmd2 args - ; echo $?) 2>&1 )    # echoes 1

echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} # echoes 0
```

Comment: What is an 'anonymous FIFO'?  There are FIFOs, which are named pipes, and pipes which are anonymous, and so could, I suppose, be termed 'anonymous FIFOs', but that isn't a commonly used term.

Comment: The `>()` syntax above. I believe you have it backwards. A pipe is one kind of FIFO rather than the other way around. Pipes are specific to shell scripts. I believe the name pipe even comes from the syntax `|`. Fifos are a more general data structure. Bash has named fifos (which act like files) and anonymous fifos (which have no filesystem abstraction) and pipes (which are another type of fifo without a filesystem abstraction).

Comment: See the `Process Substitution`in the bash man pages.

Comment: @BartonChittenden My copy of the manpage appears identical to [1] (at least the relevant section). The `Process Substitution` section doesn't mention how to get the result of `list`. [1] http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: If you want the $? of cmd2, write it to a file.

Comment: @PSkocik the whole point of using the anonymous FIFO was to avoid writing a temp file. If I went that route, I'd separate the two sets of commands entirely using files as go-betweens. Might be easier to write, but temp files should not be needed and are a pain. (Can you ensure they are deleted, where do you put them, what happens if your script runs without permissions to write, name collisions if running in parallel, etc)

Comment: Historically, pipes preceded FIFOs by many years — most of a decade, I believe.  The implementation now may be pipes as a special case of FIFO rather than vice versa, but historically, 'twas the other way round.  The `>(…)` syntax is known as [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in the manual.  It ends up mapping to a file — usually a file in /dev/fd — but I'm not sure what the type of that file is.

Comment: Naming aside, rearranging it as @John1024 suggested works well for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have not provided any specific examples of cmd1 or cmd2, it would appear that:

```
cmd1 args >( cmd2 args - )
```

could be rearranged as:

```
cmd2 args <(cmd1 args /dev/stdout); echo $?
```

where the echo statement reports on the status of `cmd2`.

#### Specific example

```
$ cat cmd1
#!/bin/sh
sed "$1" "$2" >"$3"
```

and:

```
$ cat cmd2
#!/bin/sh
grep Y "$@"
```

Let's use a test file:

```
$ cat file
input
```

Now, observe that the correct exit codes are reported:

```
$ cmd2 <( cmd1 's/input/Y/' file /dev/stdout) ; echo $?
Y
0
$ cmd2 <( cmd1 's/input/N/' file /dev/stdout) ; echo $?
1
```

Further, we can capture stdout into the variable `output`:

```
$ output=$( cmd2 <( cmd1 's/input/Y/' file /dev/stdout) ) ; echo code=$? output=$output
code=0 output=Y
$ output=$( cmd2 <( cmd1 's/input/N/' file /dev/stdout) ) ; echo code=$? output=$output
code=1 output=
```